# Request to allow copy-paste image from snipping tool into question/answer

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

Windows snipping tool has a little "copy" button, it looks like this:

[image]

If you're composing and email in gmail, you can paste right into your email with Ctrl-V after copying from the snipping tool with that button. It's very convenient.

At StackExchange sites, I have to save the snip to my hard drive first (as far as I know). The drag-and-drop functionality you have now is great for images on my hard drive. But allowing copy paste would save me from having to save the snip, and then delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already implemented.

When in the editor, click the image button:

> [image: image button highlighted]

The upload image dialog accepts pastes (Chrome):

> [image]

Comment: So it does! Thank you. It wasn't working for me before but it worked this time. I see the UI is a bit tricky, though. If you restore focus by clicking on the uploader, it opens the local disk explorer which you then have to close before pressing Ctrl-V. Or you can just use Alt-TAB in windows to switch focus back and then it works. I must not have clicked properly before.